# How to calculate the total number of pair under particular parent according to pattern 1:2,1:1 day to day maximum up to 5 pair caping daily

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project in which members are added in a tree pattern, and get the payment accordingly.

[image]

below is my table structure ,data and stored procedure

```
   CREATE TABLE Associate_Income
     (
      ID             varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      ParentID       varchar(30) NULL,
      IsLeft         tinyint     NULL,
      IsRight        tinyint     NULL,
      joingdate      datetime    NOT NULL
     )


      INSERT  Associate_Income 
       (ID,            ParentID,    IsLeft, IsRight, joingdate)
    SELECT 'Ramesh123',     NULL,         NULL,  NULL    '2014-01-03 16:31:15.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sonu',         'Ramesh123',   1,     NULL,   '2014-01-03 16:45:21.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pawan kumar',  'Ramesh123',   NULL,  1,      '2014-01-04 16:50:23.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ravi123',      'Sonu',        1,     NULL,   '2014-01-04 17:03:22.000' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Vineet123',    'Sonu',        NULL,  1,      '2014-01-04 17:26:01.000' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'dev123',       'Ravi123',     1,     NULL,   '2014-01-05 19:35:16.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mukesh123',    'Ravi123',     NULL,  1,      '2014-01-05 19:40:41.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'poonam123',    'Vineet123',   1,     NULL,   '2014-01-05 19:49:49.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'monu',         'Pawan kumar', 1,     NULL,   '2014-01-05 17:32:58.000' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Arti123',      'Pawan kumar', NULL,  1,      '2014-01-05 19:54:35.000' UNION ALL
```

My database table Associate_Income structure is as follow:

```
    ID            ParentID       IsLeft     IsRight             joingdate

    Ramesh123       NULL           NULL       NULL              2014-01-03 16:31:15.000
    Sonu            Ramesh123      1          NULL              2014-01-03 16:45:21.000
    Pawan kumar     Ramesh123      NULL       1                 2014-01-04 16:50:23.000
    Ravi123         Sonu           1          NULL              2014-01-04 17:03:22.000
    Vineet123       Sonu           NULL       1                 2014-01-04 17:26:01.000
    dev123          Ravi123        1          NULL              2014-01-05 19:35:16.000
    Mukesh123       Ravi123        NULL       1                 2014-01-05 19:40:41.000
    poonam123       Vineet123      1          NULL              2014-01-05 19:49:49.000 
    monu            Pawan kumar    1          NULL              2014-01-05 17:32:58.000
    Arti123         Pawan kumar    NULL       1                 2014-01-05 19:54:35.000
```

by using below  stored procedure I can count the total number of pairs under particular node in 2:1,1:1 ratio means first pair is completed when two node added to the left side of given parent node and one node added right side of given parent node after that all pairs are completed when one node added left side and one node added right side of parent node (1:1 ratio).

example if i execute my stored procedure as follows it would return following.

EXEC count_pairs 'Ramesh123'

3

so there is 3 pairs as shown in my figure.

when we execute my stored procedure for ParentID 'sonu' it would return following.

EXEC count_pairs 'sonu'

2

it return 2

means node 'sonu' have total 2 pairs as shown my figure but 
my problem is
how  to count total number of pairs which are completed by node  'sonu'  in day ('2014-01-03 16:31:15.000') and total number of pairs in day(2014-01-04 16:31:15.000) and total number of pairs in day(2014-01-05 16:31:15.000)

.

.

.

. up to last date as given

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[count_pairs]
(
@ParentID nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin
Declare @ParentSUM SMALLINT = 0
Declare @SubLeftID nvarchar(50)
Declare @SubRightID nvarchar(50)
SELECT @SubLeftID = CASE WHEN [IsLeft] = 1 THEN [ID] ELSE @SubLeftID END
     ,@SubRightID = CASE WHEN [IsRight] = 1 THEN [ID] ELSE @SubRightID END
FROM  Associate_Income
WHERE ParentID = @ParentID
IF @SubLeftID IS NOT NULL AND @SubRightID IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  Associate_Income
WHERE [IsLeft] = 1 AND ParentID = @SubLeftID)
BEGIN

SET @ParentSUM = 1

;WITH  Associate_Income_CTE AS
(

    SELECT [ID], [ParentID], [IsLeft], [IsRight], 0 AS [Level] 
    FROM Associate_Income
    WHERE [ParentID] = @ParentID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RecursiveMember.[ID], RecursiveMember.[ParentID], RecursiveMember.[IsLeft], RecursiveMember.[IsRight], Level + 1 
    FROM Associate_Income RecursiveMember
    INNER JOIN  Associate_Income_CTE AnchorMember
        ON RecursiveMember.[ParentID] = AnchorMember.[ID]
)
SELECT @ParentSUM = @ParentSUM + COUNT([ParentID]) 
FROM
(
    SELECT [ParentID]
          ,'IsLeft' AS [Direction]
          ,1 AS [Value]
    FROM  Associate_Income
    WHERE [IsLeft] = 1
        AND [ID] <> @ParentID --AND [ID] NOT IN (@SubLeftID, @ParentID)
        AND [ParentID] NOT IN (@ParentID, @SubLeftID)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [ParentID]
          ,'IsRight' AS [Direction]
          ,1 AS [Value]
    FROM  Associate_Income
    WHERE [IsRight] = 1
        AND [ParentID] <> @ParentID
) AS  Associate_Income
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Value]) FOR [Direction] IN ([IsLeft], [IsRight])
) PVT
WHERE [IsLeft] IS NOT NULL AND [IsRight] IS NOT NULL
END
SELECT @ParentSUM
```

Dear friends following is the result which i want when executing my stored procedure as follows for node 'Ramesh123'

```
exec count_pairs 'Ramesh123'

Result


    Joingdate             Completed Pair

     2014-01-03 13:54:35.000         0   
     2014-01-04 14:56:35.000         0
     2014-01-05 15:58:35.000         0
     2014-01-06 16:54:35.000         1
     2014-01-07 14:54:35.000         0
     2014-01-07 15:34:35.000         1
     2014-01-07 15:54:35.000         0
     2014-01-09 11:54:35.000         0
     2014-01-09 14:64:35.000         0
     2014-01-23 17:54:35.000         1
```

and for 'sonu'

exec count_pairs 'sonu'

```
Result

   Joingdate                        Completed Pair
    2014-01-03 13:54:35.000         0   
    2014-01-04 14:56:35.000         0
    2014-01-05 15:58:35.000         0
    2014-01-06 16:54:35.000         0
    2014-01-07 14:54:35.000         0
    2014-01-07 15:34:35.000         0
    2014-01-07 15:54:35.000         1
    2014-01-09 11:54:35.000         0
    2014-01-09 14:64:35.000         1
    2014-01-23 17:54:35.000         0
```

please any one can give me some your valuable advice ,idea or solution

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a question in all this?

Comment: yes it question  how to find the total number of pair under particular parent according to pattern 1:2,1:1 day to day maximum up to 5 pair caping daily