# How to calculet weekly comission in MLM Application

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, recursive-query

I am working on a Multilevel Marketing Project (MLM) in which node added in tree pattern.

please any one can give some idea how to write the stored procedure for calculate weekly commission(Income in mlm tree ) bellow is my table structure and data.

```
CREATE TABLE Associate_Income
 (
  ID             varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  ParentID       varchar(30) NULL,
  IsLeft         tinyint     NULL,
  IsRight        tinyint     NULL,
  joingdate      datetime    NOT NULL
 )


  INSERT  Associate_Income 
   (ID,            ParentID,    IsLeft, IsRight, joingdate)
SELECT 'Ramesh123',     NULL,         NULL,  NULL    '2014-01-03 16:31:15.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sonu',         'Ramesh123',   1,     NULL,   '2014-01-03 16:45:21.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pawan kumar',  'Ramesh123',   NULL,  1,      '2014-01-04 16:50:23.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ravi123',      'Sonu',        1,     NULL,   '2014-01-04 17:03:22.000' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Vineet123',    'Sonu',        NULL,  1,      '2014-01-04 17:26:01.000' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'dev123',       'Ravi123',     1,     NULL,   '2014-01-05 19:35:16.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mukesh123',    'Ravi123',     NULL,  1,      '2014-01-05 19:40:41.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 'poonam123',    'Vineet123',   1,     NULL,   '2014-01-05 19:49:49.000' UNION ALL
SELECT 'monu',         'Pawan kumar', 1,     NULL,   '2014-01-05 17:32:58.000' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Arti123',      'Pawan kumar', NULL,  1,      '2014-01-05 19:54:35.000' UNION ALL
```

My database table Associate_Income structure is as follow:

```
ID            ParentID       IsLeft     IsRight             joingdate

Ramesh123       NULL           NULL       NULL              2014-01-03 16:31:15.000
Sonu            Ramesh123      1          NULL              2014-01-03 16:45:21.000
Pawan kumar     Ramesh123      NULL       1                 2014-01-04 16:50:23.000
Ravi123         Sonu           1          NULL              2014-01-04 17:03:22.000
Vineet123       Sonu           NULL       1                 2014-01-04 17:26:01.000
dev123          Ravi123        1          NULL              2014-01-05 19:35:16.000
Mukesh123       Ravi123        NULL       1                 2014-01-05 19:40:41.000
poonam123       Vineet123      1          NULL              2014-01-05 19:49:49.000 
monu            Pawan kumar    1          NULL              2014-01-05 17:32:58.000
Arti123         Pawan kumar    NULL       1                 2014-01-05 19:54:35.000
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write a query for you?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Also post the expected result based on your sample data and the algorithm you used.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)?

Comment: i tried myself and write code but did not get actual result      please check my code and detail description on bellow link             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087884/how-to-calculate-the-total-number-of-pair-under-particular-parent-according-to-p?noredirect=1#comment31719847_21087884